# What is the smallest eularian graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-verification

[image]

Which one is smallest eularian? I think that (1,2)-eularian.

*Thank you for your helps in advance.*

Comment: The question is correct. None of the graphs you showed is eulerian. The smallest eulerian graph has 4 edges and 4 vertices.

Comment: An Eulerian graph should have an Eulerian cycle, not just an Eulerian path. Smallest is $K_3$, a triangle.